# How do I do the Delayed::Job equivalent of Process#waitall?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a large task that proceeds in several major steps: Step A must complete before Step B can be started, etc.  But each major step can be divided up across multiple processes, in my case, using `Delayed::Job`.

The question: Is there a simple technique for starting Step B only after all the processes have completed working on Step A?

Note 1: I don't know *a priori* how many external workers have been spun up, so keeping a reference count of completed workers won't help.

Note 2: I'd prefer not to create a worker whose sole job is to busy wait for the other jobs to complete.  Heroku workers cost money!

Note 3: I've considered having each worker examine the Delayed::Job queue in the `after` callback to decide if it's the last one working on Step A, in which case it could initiate Step B.  This could work, but seems potentially fraught with gotchas.  (In the absence of better answers, this is the approach I'm going with.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on the specifics of what you are doing, but you could set priority levels such that any jobs from Step A run first. Depending on the specifics, that might be enough. From the [github page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job):

> By default all jobs are scheduled with priority = 0, which is top
>   priority. You can change this by setting
>   Delayed::Worker.default_priority to something else. Lower numbers have
>   higher priority.

So if you set Step A to run at priority = 0, and Step B to run at priority = 100, nothing in Step B will run until Step A is complete.

There's some cases where this will be problematic -- in particular, if you have a lot of jobs and are running a lot of workers, you will probably have some workers running Step B before the work in Step A is finished. Ideally in this setup, Step B has some sort of check to make check if it can be run or not.

Comment: I tried this approach -- even with priorities, Step B tasks will start if one or more Step A tasks have failed and are waiting for retries.  As you point out, tasks in Step B need need to check that Step A has *really* finished.